# WP7 swipe gesture on pivot page is changing toggleswitch value

Tags: windows-phone-7, swipe-gesture

I have a toggleswitch on a pivot page.  When the user 'swipes' the page, it moves to the next pivot element.  This is great functionality.  However, when the swipe starts with a 'tap' on the toggleswitch, the value of the toggleswitch changes.  this leads to confusion as the change occurs during the pivot transition and the user's configuration has magically reverted to another value.

Does anyone have suggestions on how to stop this behavior?  Or suggestions on how to mitigate it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't do this as it's not good UI practice. You should either have the toggle on a separate, non-pivot page or you could use a checkbox instead. If, however, you want to keep the toggle switch on a pivot control, then this [blog post](http://mine.tuxfamily.org/?p=111) might help explain how to get it to work.

Comment: This isn't just limited to toggleswitches on pivotItems. You shouldn't put a control which supports a gestures on top of another control which also supports that same gesture.